# matplotlib title, and axes tick marks, not working with 5D np array (but do work with 3D array)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, astropy

Exact code:

```
    def sanity(self) :
        for frame in self._input : 
            plt.figure      ( )
            plt.imshow      ( frame )
            plt.xlim        ( [ 0, frame.shape[1] ] ) 
            plt.ylim        ( [ 0, frame.shape[0] ] )
            plt.title       ("  S A N I T Y   C H E C K  ")

    def outputFramesXPR(self) :
        log2("self._output.shape : ", self._output.shape)
        squeeze2 = np.squeeze(self._output, axis = 2)
        log2("squeeze2.shape     : ", squeeze2.shape)
        squeeze0 = np.squeeze(squeeze2, axis = 0)
        log2("squeeze0.shape     : ", squeeze0.shape)
        for frame in squeeze0 :
            plt.figure      ( )
            plt.imshow      ( frame )
            plt.xlim        ( [ 0, frame.shape[1] ] ) 
            plt.ylim        ( [ 0, frame.shape[0] ] )
            plt.title       ("  O U T P U T   F R A M E S  ")
```

Function "sanity" loops through a 3D numpy array and the plot titles appear in the final images.
Every image has the exact title in the exact place where the title should go.
Every image has the exact x axis tick marks where and in what direction they should go.
Every image has the exact y axis tick marks where and in what direction they should go.

Function "outputFrames Experimental" loops through / gets through a 5D numpy array.
I squeeze out the third dimension which is flat (1).
I'm down to four dimensions.
I squeeze out the first dimension which is flat (1).
I'm down to three dimensions.
I give a plot title 'output frames'.
This is the textual output generated from the print statements:

```
1207 self._output.shape :  (1, 4, 1, 79, 110) 
1210 squeeze2.shape     :  (1, 4, 79, 110) 
1212 squeeze0.shape     :  (4, 79, 110)
```

The frames I am attempting to label present themselves solely as the images.
There is zero title, zero x axis tick marks, zero y axis tick marks.
Only the image.
*IF I OMIT* the call to plt.ylim, i.e., if I comment that line out, the image is flipped vertically. That is a default condition for the working 'sanity' images, as well, so that tells me that somewhere in the guts matplotlib at least hears that I am trying to plot it according to ascending y. So if it hears my request enough to plot the image in the User's preferred vertical sense, what is stopping it from also plotting title, y tick marks, and x tick marks?

Is there something fundamentally different about squeezing a 5D array to 3D with respect to how matplotlib interprets calls to plot the data ... from native plotting out of a 3D array, where everything just seems to work?

Comment: what is `frame`? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: "frame" is just a 2D plot. Many 2D plots, called "frame", inside the 3D array that I am looping over.

Comment: There is no loop in your second function

Comment: Shoot - I added that back in. It got dropped while copying and cleaning. Is there some kind of standard image hosting service that Stack Overflow uses, or, can you upload images to Stack Overflow? I could upload samples of these outcomes.

Comment: You code seems to work fine for me. Please refer to [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) again. You need to provide some code that one can simply copy and paste to reproduce the problem. Including an example (possibly randomly generated) 5D array.

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to have anything to do with your array shape, but something with how you're using matplotlib itself. I agree with the requests for a Minimal, Verifiable Example, because it should also help clarify your own thinking. Start from scratch and see if you can reproduce the problem with a simple example.

Comment: "Is there something fundamentally different about squeezing a 5D array to 3D with respect to how matplotlib interprets calls to plot the data" no, absolutely not. Whatever the problem is it has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Mac Catalina (at least 10.15.5) :
If you perform multiprocessing:
If you imported plt and used prior to the multiprocessing:
You're going to have limited ability to use matplotlib to its capacity, particularly with respect to character printing.

Fix:
If you're on Mac Catalina (at least 10.15.5) :
If you perform multiprocessing:
Save forward all numpy arrays that you intend to plot out until you have passed all uses of multiprocessing, and then import matplotlib.
At least in my case, I am now able to print out titles and tick mark labels.

This is a known bug for Catalina. I knew it earlier in this project. I forgot about it. I bit me. I asked a question here on stack overflow in complete oblivion of this one gotcha. The answer is this here. If Catalina, don't import matplotlib until you've finished multiprocessing. In my case the plots that had printing were before I used multiprocessing, and the plots that did not get printing were after I used multiprocessing.

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/15410
"Change in OSX Catalina makes matplotlib + multiprocessing crash #15410"